# Error while downgrading to lower version of Intel management engine interface

Tags: windows-10, drivers, sleep, setup, intel-core-i5

I've HP laptop and due to some sleep issues I was suggested to downgrade my Intel management engine Interface driver so as to resolve the issue and while running the setup I'm getting the error **"This computer does not meet the minimum requirements for installing the software"**, although I've taken the setup from HP site and also done according to their steps in this link(https://support.hp.com/lt-en/document/c03383935 in "Sleep and Hibernate issues after upgrading to Windows 10" section).

**My laptop specs:**
HP Pavilion Laptop  15-cc1xx
Windows 10 Home 64 bit
8GB Ram
Intel i5-8250U

I want to downgrade it from version 11 to version 9.5 as it was told that it works fine in most of the PCs. Please help me downgrade this driver.

Comment: I have V 11.8.79 on my Lenovo laptop and it is not interfering in Sleep in any way. Have you also updated BIOS, Chipset, Video and Power Drivers as well.  Use the HP Driver Update App.

Comment: Maybe this article can give you some help. https://thegeekpage.com/rollback-intel-r-management-engine-interface-driver-in-windows-10/

Comment: @John Yes this issue actually started after a bios update.            I'm trying to find the old version( version F.33) of bios for my HP laptop
The product name is HP Pavilion 15-cc1xx 
Sepcs: Intel i5-8250U
8gb ram
Laptop name 15-cc152od

I actually know to site where hp has all setups ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq

But, I can't find my bios version setup. If you know a site that keeps track of all hp setup releases with file names please help.